# RCPP_MODULE for inheritance class

Tags: r, rcpp

I got a problem when I try module with inheritance class. Basiclly, I can't compile this part.

```
RCPP_MODULE(PACE){
    using namespace Rcpp;
    class_<FPCAreg>("FPCAreg")
        .constructor<List, List, double, double, int, bool, bool>()
        .field("n", &FPCAreg::n)
            ;
}
```

Here FPCAreg is a inheritance class based on FPCA class, and "n" is defined in FPCA. No matter I use ".field("n", &FPCAreg::n)" or ".field("n", &FPCA::n)". When I use ".field("n", &FPCAreg::n)", the error message is "no matching function for call to blablabla", and for ".field("n", &FPCA::n)", that's same but different class name. Is there any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: You cross-posted here AND on rcpp-devel. That is bad form. Pick one, or the other.  I replied on list.  [ And no, I have not downvoted. ]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only declare fields and methods from the actual class. However, what you can do is expose the base class and the derived class, and hint the inheritance between them in `derives`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class Base {
public:
    Base(double x_) : x(x_){}
    double x; 
} ;

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int y_) : Base(2.0), y(y_){} 
    int y ;
} ;

RCPP_MODULE(PACE){
    class_<Base>("Base")
        .constructor<double>()
        .field("x", &Base::x) 
    ;
    class_<Derived>("Derived")
        .derives<Base>("Base")
        .constructor<int>()
        .field("y", &Derived::y)
    ;
}
```

I get this then from R:

```
> obj <- new(Derived, 10L)
> obj$y
[1] 10
> obj$x
[1] 2
```

Comment: The usual way to express that is to accept the answer.