# Exposing inherited methods through the derived object using Rcpp modules

Tags: r, inheritance, rcpp

I have an almost empty Rcpp project created using the method described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63088185/862288). The contents of `rcpp_hello_world.cpp` have been replaced with:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

class A {
public:
  virtual int foo() {
    return 1;
  }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  int bar() {
    return 2;
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int fun() {
  B b;
  return b.foo();
}

RCPP_MODULE(mod_ab) {
  class_<A>("A").
    constructor().
    method("foo", &A::foo);

  class_<B>("B")
    .constructor()
    //.method("foo", &B::foo)
    .method("bar", &B::bar);
}
```

`B` publicly derives from `A` so it should be possible to call methods from `A` through `B` as done in function `fun()`. How can I expose this method through `RCPP_MODULES`? If I uncomment the line

```
    //.method("foo", &B::foo)
```

I get the following error:

```
rcpp_hello_world.cpp: In function ‘void _rcpp_module_mod_ab_init()’:
rcpp_hello_world.cpp:31:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘Rcpp::class_<B>::method(const char [4], int (A::*)())’
     .method("foo", &B::foo)
```

Is it possible to do this or should I create a method in `B` that forwards to its base class and expose that?

Comment: It seems the answer is described [here](http://www.deanbodenham.com/learn/rcpp-classes-part-5.html). Basically it seems you'll need to expose the derived class and the derived method using `.derives<A>("A")`.

Comment: Which in turn points to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24317910/rcpp-module-for-inheritance-class so this is a duplicate.